# PostgreSQL can't find column

Tags: java, postgresql

I create a database that contains 4 column (ID_PRODUIT,NOM_PRODUIT,QUANTITE, PRIX).I tried to make a methods that allow me to serach Product(my class)using a string key,however, the query failed to identify the "NOM_PRODUIT" column and it turn "NOM_PRODUIT" to "nom_produit" in the messsage error.

```
     Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, passwd);

     PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FrOM produits where NOM_PRODUIT like ?");

     ps.setString(1,"%"+mc+"%");
     ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
     while(rs.next()){
         Produit p=new Produit();System.out.println(rs.getString(2));
         p.setIdProduit(rs.getInt(1));
         p.setNomProduit(rs.getString(2));
         p.setQuantite(rs.getInt(3));
         p.setPrix(rs.getInt(4));

     }
     ps.close();
     conn.close();
```

I get this error :

```
  org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERREUR: la colonne « nom_produit » n'existe pas
```

Here's my database.[image]

Comment: Could you post the DDL definition of the `produits` table?

Comment: is this the full stacktrace? or have you cut pasted?

Comment: `nom_produit` is not the same as `"NOM_PRODUIT"`. See the manual for details: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS In a nutshell: avoid quoted identifiers when _creating_ your tables.

Comment: CREATE TABLE produits
(
  "ID_PRODUIT" integer NOT NULL,
  "NOM_PRODUIT" character(50),
  "QUANTITE" integer,
  "PRIX" integer,
  CONSTRAINT produits_pkey PRIMARY KEY ("ID_PRODUIT")
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE produits
  OWNER TO postgres;

Comment: it 's an upper case issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case the issue it related to upper and lower case in the column name: it's possible to put the column name in double quotes:

```
 PreparedStatement ps = 
    conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM produits where \"NOM_PRODUIT\" like ?");
```

This way the name is case sensitive.

Comment: It is not clear if this is the cause. If the column name is unquoted when creating the table then either form is acceptable, uppercase or lowercase, if unquoted.

Comment: I know and I saw you asked for the DDL which has not been added yet. That is the reason why I started with _"Just in case...."_ ;) and as you correctly pointed out: it might only be an issue, if the column has been created with double quotes.

Comment: It seems that was an upper case issue . Your solution has worked .Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
 ps.setString(1,"%"+mc+"%");
```

you are missing single quote ', try

```
ps.setString(1,"'%"+mc+"%'");
```